# how to concatenate lists in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to insert a String into a list.

I got this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

because I tried this:

```
var1 = 'ThisIsAString' # My string I want to insert in the following list
file_content = open('myfile.txt').readlines()
new_line_insert = file_content[:10] + list(var1) + rss_xml[11:]
open('myfile.txt', 'w').writelines(new_line_insert)
```

The content of myfile.txt is saved in "file_content" as a list.
I want to insert the String var1 after the 10th line, thats why I did

```
file_content[:10] + list(var1) + rss_xml[11:]
```

but the list(var1) doesn't work. How can I make this code work?
Thanks!

Comment: You talk about inserting in a list, but you have file_content[:10] and rss_xml[11:]. First those are two different lists (and here I'm assuming that rss_xml *is* a list), and second you will miss out the 10th element doing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
file_content[:10] + [var1] + rss_xml[11:]
```

Answer (score 3):

Lists have an insert method, so you could just use that:

```
file_content.insert(10, var1)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note the "list(var1)" is trying to convert var1 to a list.  Since var1 is a string, it will be something like:

```
>>> list('this')
['t', 'h', 'i', 's']
```

Or, in other words, it converts the string to a **list** of characters.  This is different from creating a list where var1 is an element, which is most easily accomplished by putting the "[]" around the element:

```
>>> ['this']
['this']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file_content = file_content[:10]
file_content.append(var1)
file_content.extend(rss_xml[11:])
```